# Regular expression errors

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have a simple problem, but somehow it looks like I am retarded today.

I want to mach all strings that begin with % and end with %. `%This%` is a valid match.
Here is what I wrote :

```
$data = "This should %work% here";
preg_match_all('/%(.*?)%/g', $data, $loco);
echo var_dump($loco);
```

Somehow I get $loco = NULL. What is the problem with my regex ?!

Comment: Works fine for me! (I just removed g as modifier)

Comment: @Rizier123 $loco is not NULL ?

Comment: Nope see: http://ideone.com/0sSbQU

Comment: In JS, you need the `g` modifier, but in PHP, the existence of `preg_match` and `preg_match_all` makes it rather redundant. ditch it and you'll be fine (ps: `'/%([^%]+)%/'` would be a better pattern IMHO)

Comment: i think it's because of the `g` modifier. You don't need to include that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$data = "This should %work% here";
preg_match_all('/%(.*?)%/i', $data, $loco);
echo var_dump($loco);
```

Answer (score 2):

`g` isn't a valid modifier.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Remove it, and it will work fine.